# Angular NgRx - Effect to continue polling a service only called the first time

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an application where I have just added NgRX where I wish to use effects to switch polling on and off.

**Sample outline**

I followed [this post](https://bbonczek.github.io/jekyll/update/2018/03/01/polling-with-ngrx.html) which seemed like a good approach. I have a simplified example of this [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-polling2), with the bulk of the code is in `app.effects.ts`.

Similar to the example, I have the effects `startPolling$`, `stopPolling$` and `continuePolling$`, except I am using the newer `createEffect` factory methods.

Also, I have moved the `delay(2000)`above the `takeWhile()`, as I found if the service call throws an error, the the `catchError(err => of(appActions.getDataFail(err)))` would cause the effect to go into an continuous very fast loop without the delay.

The start and stop button dispatches the polling start and stop...

```
public start() {
    console.log('dispatching start');
    this.store.dispatch(appActions.startPolling());
  }

  public stop() {
    console.log('dispatching stop');
    this.store.dispatch(appActions.stopPolling());
  }
```

**My Problem**

I have some console logs so we can see what is going on.

When we click the **start button** (just the **first** time), I can see the polling start, and continue as expected. Eg I can see the following over and over...

```
dispatching start
app effect started polling
app.service.getData
app effect continue polling
app.service.getData
app effect continue polling
app.service.getData
app effect continue polling
```

Perfect.

And when I hit the stop I see

```
dispatching stop
app effect stop polling
```

Also correct.

Now, the problem, **is when I try to restart**. If I now click the start button again, all I see is the initial start polling effect...

```
dispatching start
app effect started polling
app.service.getData
```

and the code in **`continuePolling$`is no longer being called**, so I have no polling.

Why is this effect not triggered the second time? I just cannot work out why this is.

### Update 1

I think perhaps my problem is that once `isPollingActive` is set to false, and `takeWhile(() => this.isPollingActive),` "stops", the observable is no longer active, ie the `continuePolling$` complete, so will never restart?

Assuming this, I tried the following where I have 2 different variables, one to "pause" the polling (eg if I detect the app in an offline mode), and another to cancel (ie when the user would navigate out of the component).

So, my whole effects now becomes...

```
    @Injectable()
    export class AppEffects {
      private isPollingCancelled: boolean;
      private isPollingPaused: boolean;

      constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private store: Store<AppState>,
        private appDataService: AppDataService
      ) { }

      public startPolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(appActions.startPolling),
        tap(_ => console.log('app effect started polling')),
        tap(() => {
          this.isPollingCancelled = false;
          this.isPollingPaused = false;
        }),        
          mergeMap(() =>
            this.appDataService.getData()
              .pipe(                        
                switchMap(data => {              
                  return [appActions.getDataSuccess(data)
                  ];
                  }),
                catchError(err => of(appActions.getDataFail(err)))
              ))
        ));

         public pausePolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(appActions.pausePolling),
            tap(_ => this.isPollingPaused = true),
            tap(_ => console.log('app effect pause polling')),       
         ));
      
      public cancelPolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(appActions.cancelPolling),
        tap(_ => this.isPollingCancelled = true),
        tap(_ => console.log('app effect cancel polling')),
      ));

        public continuePolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType(appActions.getDataSuccess, appActions.getDataFail),    
          tap(data => console.log('app effect continue polling')),  
          takeWhile(() => !this.isPollingCancelled),    
          delay(3000),  
     
          mergeMap(() =>
            this.appDataService.getData()
              .pipe(   
                delay(3000),  
                tap(data => console.log('app effect continue polling - inner loop')),  
                takeWhile(() => !this.isPollingPaused), // check again incase this has been unset since delay 
                switchMap(data => {              
                  return [appActions.getDataSuccess(data)
                  ];
                  }),
                catchError(err => of(appActions.getDataFail(err)))
              ))
        ));    
    }
```

I would not recommend running the above as when I then dispatch a `pause polling action`, the effect seem to get into an endless loop, and I have to kill the browser via task manager.

I have no ideas why this is happening, but I appear to be further from a solution than before.

### Update 2

I noticed I was not returning any actions from the pause and cancel effects.

So I have updated them we follows...

```
 public pausePolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(appActions.pausePolling),
    tap(_ => this.isPollingPaused = true),
    tap(_ => console.log('app effect pause polling')),
    map(_ => appActions.pausePollingSuccess())
  ));
  
  public cancelPolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(appActions.cancelPolling),
    tap(_ => {
      this.isPollingCancelled = true;
      this.isPollingPaused = true;
    }),
    tap(_ => console.log('app effect cancel polling')),
    map(_ => appActions.cancelPollingSuccess())
  ));
```

Now the pause seems to work OK, but when I dispatch the `appActions.cancelPolling`, I again see like an infinite loop of `app effect cancel polling` being logged to the console.

### Update 3

I have found why I get the infinite loop and how to stop it. According to the doco [here](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle#non-dispatching-effects), I can add the `dispatch:false`...

```
    public cancelPolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(appActions.cancelPolling),
        tap(_ => {
          this.isPollingCancelled = true;
          this.isPollingPaused = true;
        }),
        tap(_ => console.log('app effect cancel polling')),
      ), { dispatch: false }); // <------ add this
```

and this seems to fix my infinite loop.

My only task now is to be able to work out how to be able to start, stop, and restart the polling handling both success calls to `appDataService.getData()` as well as for exceptions.

I can get it working for one or the other (depending on where I put the delay and takewhile), but not for both

### Update 4

I have the latest code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-polling3).

Running it as is, I have the getData succeed, and surprisingly, either the pause OR stop action will stop it and allow it to restart.. I am surprised the **stop** action allows it to restart, as I was assuming the `takeWhile(() => !this.isPollingCancelled),` would cancel the effect.

Also, if `true`is passed to `getData` this will cause it's observable to error. The polling continues (as wanted, ie still retry even on error), but once we now when we dispatch the pause action, it does NOT stop polling, and it we dispatch the stop, it DOES stop, but then it will not restart. I cannot win.

### Update 5

I thought perhaps since the continue polling effect gets cancelled, I could just recreate it each time, as below..

```
    import { Injectable, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { createEffect, Actions, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
    import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
    import { mergeMap, map, catchError, takeWhile, delay, tap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { AppState } from './app.state';
    import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
    import { AppDataService } from '../app-data.service';
    import * as appActions from './app.actions';

    @Injectable()
    export class AppEffects {
      private isPollingCancelled: boolean;
      private isPollingPaused: boolean;

      constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private store: Store<AppState>,
        private appDataService: AppDataService
      ) { }

      public startPolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(appActions.startPolling),
        tap(_ => console.log('app effect started polling')),
        tap(() => {
          this.isPollingCancelled = false;
          this.isPollingPaused = false;
          this.createPollingEffect(); // <--- recreate the effect every time
        }),        
          mergeMap(() =>
            this.appDataService.getData()
              .pipe(                        
                switchMap(data => {              
                  return [appActions.getDataSuccess(data)
                  ];
                  }),
                catchError(err => of(appActions.getDataFail(err)))
              ))
        ));

      public pausePolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(appActions.pausePolling),
        tap(_ => this.isPollingPaused = true),
        tap(_ => console.log('app effect pause polling')),
      ), { dispatch: false });
      
      public cancelPolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(appActions.cancelPolling),
        tap(_ => {
          this.isPollingCancelled = true;
          this.isPollingPaused = true;
        }),
        tap(_ => console.log('app effect cancel polling')),
      ), { dispatch: false });

      public continuePolling$: any;

      private createPollingEffect(): void {
        console.log('creating continuePolling$');
        this.continuePolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType(appActions.getDataSuccess, appActions.getDataFail),
          tap(data => console.log('app effect continue polling')),
          delay(3000),
          takeWhile(() => !this.isPollingCancelled),
          mergeMap(() =>
            this.appDataService.getData(false)
              .pipe(
                tap(data => console.log('app effect continue polling - inner loop')),

                switchMap(data => {
                  return [appActions.getDataSuccess(data)
                  ];
                }),
                catchError(err => of(appActions.getDataFail(err)))
              ))
        ), { resubscribeOnError: true });
      } 
    }
```

So, in the `startPolling` I call `this.createPollingEffect()` to create the continue polling effect.

However, when I tried this, the polling never starts.

### Update 6

I have come up with a solution that seems to work for me.

I have the following

```
public startPolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(dataActions.startPollingGetData),
        tap(_ => this.logger.info('effect start polling')),
        tap(() => this.isPollingActive = true),
        switchMap(_ => this.syncData())
      ), { dispatch: false });
      
    public continuePolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(dataPlannerActions.DataSuccess,
          dataActions.DataFail),
        tap(_ => this.logger.debug('data effect continue polling')),
        tap(_ => this.isInDelay = true),
        delay(8000),
        tap(_ => this.isInDelay = false),
        switchMap(_ => this.syncData())
      ), { dispatch: false });


    public stopPolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(dataActions.stopPollingData),
        tap(_ => this.isPollingActive = false),
        tap(_ => this.logger.info('data effect stop polling')),
        map(_ => dataActions.stopPollingDataSuccess())
      ), { dispatch: false });


    private syncData(): Observable<Action> {
        const result$: Observable<Action> = Observable.create(async subscriber => {
          try {
            // If polling "switched off", we just need to return anything (not actually used)
            // Id isInDelay, we may be restating while we still have a pending delay.
            // In this case we will exit, and just wait for the delay to restart
            // (otherwise we can end up with more than one call to this)
            if (this.isInDelay || !this.isPollingActive) {
              subscriber.next("");
              return;
            }
```

I use a couple of "flags" here, I am sure thee would be a more "rxy" way of doing this.

In fact, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220897/rxjs-ngrx-is-there-a-way-to-cancel-a-stream-after-the-delay-operator) on how to possibly get rid of the `isInDelay` (I just need to get around to putting this into my production code above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this as part of my question/discussion, but thought would put as a solution to make a little more visible...

I have come up with a solution that seems to work for me.

I have the following

```
public startPolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(dataActions.startPollingGetData),
        tap(_ => this.logger.info('effect start polling')),
        tap(() => this.isPollingActive = true),
        switchMap(_ => this.syncData())
      ), { dispatch: false });

    public continuePolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(dataPlannerActions.DataSuccess,
          dataActions.DataFail),
        tap(_ => this.logger.debug('data effect continue polling')),
        tap(_ => this.isInDelay = true),
        delay(8000),
        tap(_ => this.isInDelay = false),
        switchMap(_ => this.syncData())
      ), { dispatch: false });


    public stopPolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(dataActions.stopPollingData),
        tap(_ => this.isPollingActive = false),
        tap(_ => this.logger.info('data effect stop polling')),
        map(_ => dataActions.stopPollingDataSuccess())
      ), { dispatch: false });


    private syncData(): Observable<Action> {
        const result$: Observable<Action> = Observable.create(async subscriber => {
          try {
            // If polling "switched off", we just need to return anything (not actually used)
            // Id isInDelay, we may be restating while we still have a pending delay.
            // In this case we will exit, and just wait for the delay to restart
            // (otherwise we can end up with more than one call to this)
            if (this.isInDelay || !this.isPollingActive) {
              subscriber.next("");
              return;
            }
```

I use a couple of "flags" here, I am sure thee would be a more "rxy" way of doing this.

In fact, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220897/rxjs-ngrx-is-there-a-way-to-cancel-a-stream-after-the-delay-operator) on how to possibly get rid of the `isInDelay` (I Just need to get around to putting this into my production code above)

Answer (score 1):

Use that instead:

```
public startPolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(appActions.startPolling),    
  tap(_ => console.log('app effect started polling')),  
  tap(() => this.isPollingActive = true),        
  switchMap(() =>
    this.appDataSurvice.getData()
      .pipe(                        
        exhaustMap(data => {              
          return [appActions.getDataSuccess(data)];
        }),
        catchError(err => of(appActions.getDataFail(err)))
      ))
));
```

Comment: @MoxxiMangarn thanks for the reply, but I changed to the above, and the polling still did not start the second time.I have your modifications [folked here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-polling2-fixed)

Answer (score 0):

The way you have approached the problem is commendable. I faced exactly the same issue with restarting polling and this article helped me.

One issue which i am facing now is, if the polling is re-started in less than 3 seconds(timer specified), there are multiple calls to the service . In other words, the polling pauses/stops completely only after the interval has passed. So if you try to start it again before the timer elapsed, there are multiple threads that run. Just added timestamp in the service call @ https://angular-ngrx-polling3-j7b8st.stackblitz.io

The call to service happens twice with each poll.

Comment: thanks for that.If you look at UPDATE6 in the question, I have put what I ended up using. It may not be the purest in the `rxjs` sense, but all testing so far, works for me. To stop the "multiple executions" is you stop/start the polling while in the delay, I added the `this.isInDelay` flag. See the link for what looks to be a better "more rx" solution, but so far the above has worked for me, and I non longer get the build up of "threads" (yes I Know they are not really threads) doing the polling

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the reply. This helps :)

Comment: If was helpful, I might put as a solution, just so is more visible for any others.

Comment: Yes. I used the solution provided at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220897/rxjs-ngrx-is-there-a-way-to-cancel-a-stream-after-the-delay-operator . I have tested all scenarios positive so far.

Answer (score 0):

Based on inputs from @peterc and @Ingo Bürk, i was able to test all scenarios positive. Below is how my code looks.

```
@Effect()
      getPageData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(actions.StartLoading),
        tap(() => {
          this.appService.isPollingActive = true;
        }),
        mergeMap(() =>
          this.appService.getData().pipe(
            switchMap((response: GridDataResponse) => {
              return [new actions.DoneLoading(response.data)];
            }),
            retry(1),
            catchError(err => {
              return of(new actions.FailedLoading());
            })
          ))
      );

      @Effect()
      public stopPolling$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(actions.StopPolling),
        tap(_ => {
          this.appService.isPollingActive = false;
        }),
        mergeMap(() => {
          return [new actions.ResetLoading()];
        })
      );

      @Effect()
      public continuePolling$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(actions.DoneLoading,
          actions.FailedLoading),
        switchMap(_ =>
          timer(this.appService.pollingTimer).pipe(
            takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType(actions.StopPolling))),
            mergeMap(() =>
            this.appService.getData().pipe(
              takeWhile(() => this.appService.isPollingActive),
              switchMap((response: GridDataResponse) => {
                return [new actions.DoneLoading(response.data)];
              }),
              catchError(err => {
                return of(new actions.FailedLoading());
              })
            ))
          )
      )
      );
```