# Angular NgRx - is it bad practice to use store.dispatch in an effect?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

This question is an extension from [this ongoing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58426291/angular-ngrx-effect-to-continue-polling-a-service-only-called-the-first-time), but I feel it is narrower in scope and I may be able to get an answer independently to the linked post.

**Background**

In the linked post, I am trying to poll a service to get data (where my problem is turing the polling on and off). In my real world app, the call is actually a little more complicated. What I want to do is some optional http `POSTs, and then a GET, always after my`POSTS` have returned (so I Know the server has processed the POSTed data, and will be included in my next GET results.

If I do a `POST`, I also want to dispatch an action so I can update my state indicating the POST has occurred.

I have converted some of the observables to promises, as I just find async/await easier to understand than lots of observables switch/mapping etc - I know this is probably not very pure, but perhaps one day my `rx/js` operator knowledge will improve (I can only hope). Maybe someone can show my better alternative... (but this is not the main question)

**Actual Question**

I have the following code **effect code**, that does NOT dispatch of is't own actions (these will be done in `this.syncData`) ....

```
    public startPolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(myActions.startPolling),    
        tap(_ => this.logger.info('effect start polling')),
        tap(() => this.isPollingActive = true),
        switchMap(_ => this.syncData())
      ), { dispatch: false });
```

And then the helper method is...

```
    private syncData(): Observable<Action> {        
        const result$: Observable<Action> = Observable.create(async subscriber => {
          try {             
            const pendingEdits = await this.store$.select(fromData.getPendingEditedData).pipe(take(1)).toPromise()
            const pendingNewData = await this.store$.select(fromData.getNewData).pipe(take(1)).toPromise();

            // First post any local updates. These both block, so once they finish we can get the server data knowing any posted
            // data will be included
            if (pendingEdits.length > 0) {
              await this.dataService.postPendinEdits(pendingEdits).toPromise();
              this.store$.dispatch(myActions.editSuccess());
            }

            if (pendingNewData.length > 0) {
              await this.dataService.postPendingNewData(pendingNewData).toPromise();
              this.store$.dispatch(myActions.addNewDataSuccess());
            }

            const dataResult$ = this.dataService.getAllData().pipe(          
              tap(data => {
                this.previousResultsTimeUtc = data.previousResultsTimeUtc;
                if (data.currentDay) {
                  this.store$.dispatch(myActions.getCurrentDaySuccess(data.currentDay));
                  this.store$.dispatch(myActions.getDataSuccess(data));               
                } else {              
                  this.store$.dispatch((myActions.getDataSuccess(data));               
                }
              }),          
              catchError(err => of(myActions.getDataFail(err)))
            );
            const subs2 = dataResult$.subscribe(ss => {
              subs2.unsubscribe();
              subscriber.next(ss);
            });        
          } catch (error) {
            subscriber.error(error);
          }      
        })

        return result$;
      }
```

So, we can see in the helper method, I get bits of store state, as well as **dispatch actions**. Also, in my app, I have another `continuePolling` effect where I also want to call the same code in `syncData()`.

The main question is, **is it a bad idea to dispatch these actions using `this.store$.dispatch` as oppose to just returning multiple actions from the effect?**

Does using the `this.store$.dispatch` cause more of the selects to "fire" (hence more UI updating) where if I returned them all from the effect, this would first process all actions in the reducers before UI updates occur via `selects`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't expect `syncData` to dispatch actions. 
I would rather see it return an action and let `ngrx/effects` handle the dispatching of actions.

Performance wise it should be the same.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did try and make the `syncData()` return a list of actions, and have the effect return them, but I just could not get it to work. I am sure it is possible, and would be very interested in how this could actually be done. It makes it harder that some actions are not always added (their creation depends on current state)