# Is there a way to "Cancel" a stream after the delay operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am using a polling scheme in my Angular application using NgRx.

To simplify things, I have something like the following:

```
    public stopPolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(actions.stopPolling),
        tap(_ => this.isPollingActive = false),    
        map(_ => actions.stopPolling())
      ), { dispatch: false });
     
     public continuePolling$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(actions.getData),
        tap(_ => this.logger.debug('continue polling')),    
        delay(8000),    
        switchMap(_ => this.pollData())
      ), { dispatch: false });


    private pollData() {
       if (!this.isPollingActive)
         return;
    }
```

In my "StopPolling" I set a flag, but if it is restarted (ie isPollingActive is et back to true) while I am in the `delay(8000)`, the delay will exit and I will end up with the getData being called multiple times.

So, my question is, is there a way to step the `switchMap(_ => this.pollData())` being called after the delay - ie is there someway to "force the delay to exit" before the timeout period?

Almost (if you know C#/.net). like a `manualResetEvent.WaitOne(8000)` which can be cancelled by calling `Set()` on the manualResetEvent object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an observable that emits after a delay using `timer` and unsubscribe with `takeUntil` to exit early:

```
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(actions.getData),
  tap(_ => this.logger.debug('continue polling')),   
  switchMap(_ =>
    timer(8000).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType(actions.stopPolling))),
      concatMap(() => this.pollData())
    )
)
```

This might also allow you to remove the side-effect `this.isPollingActive = false` and ensure that the control flow remains within the observable.